# MIssing semicolon error in stored procedure mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

HI I am new to mysql and trying to update table through stored procedure.I am getting "missing semicolon error.I tried everything but I couldn't able to understand why is this happening.

procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS abc;
use smartdata;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE abc(IN datasourceId int)
begin

        update DM_Sample_Search_Param_Disposition_Type set DM_Sample_Search_Param_Disposition_Type.Active = 0
        From DM_Sample_Search_Param_Disposition_Type dm_ss_param_cl
        left join DM_Sample_Search_Param dm_ss_param on dm_ss_param_cl.DM_Sample_Search_Param_id =dm_ss_param.DM_Sample_Search_Param_id
        left join DM_Sample_Store dm_ss on dm_ss.DM_Sample_Store_Id=dm_ss_param.DM_Sample_Store_Id
        where dm_ss.Datasource_Id=datasourceId;

end $$
DELIMITER //
```

Error in near below line:

```
set DM_Sample_Search_Param_Disposition_Type.Active = 0
```

where "Active" is tinyint in the table.Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL uses a different syntax for update than MSSQL: `update ... join .. set ... where ...`

```
update DM_Sample_Search_Param_Disposition_Type dm_ss_param_cl
left join DM_Sample_Search_Param dm_ss_param on dm_ss_param_cl.DM_Sample_Search_Param_id =dm_ss_param.DM_Sample_Search_Param_id
left join DM_Sample_Store dm_ss on dm_ss.DM_Sample_Store_Id=dm_ss_param.DM_Sample_Store_Id
set DM_Sample_Search_Param_Disposition_Type.Active = 0
where dm_ss.Datasource_Id=datasourceId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong join table  sintax

```
update DM_Sample_Search_Param_Disposition_Type as dm_ss_param_cl
left join DM_Sample_Search_Param dm_ss_param on dm_ss_param_cl.DM_Sample_Search_Param_id =dm_ss_param.DM_Sample_Search_Param_id
left join DM_Sample_Store dm_ss on dm_ss.DM_Sample_Store_Id=dm_ss_param.DM_Sample_Store_Id
set DM_Sample_Search_Param_Disposition_Type.Active = 0
where dm_ss.Datasource_Id=datasourceId;
```